# Nested Forms, Validations and Error Messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, error-handling, nested-forms

So after two days of reading up on this topic I feel lost between problems in older versions of rails and some individual stuff that I probably did wrong.

I have a form where a User can create an account. Every user needs to put in his number plate and a car is created if it does not yet exist with that number plate and assigned to the user.
My form shows the validation error messages for the user, but not for the car (it only marks the input fields for the number plates red).

So my questions is: How do I get the error messages to render be shown properly?
I also suspect after all the topics I read, that my user controller might be doing some stuff that I should not do manually.

My form:

```
 <%= form_for(@user, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>
 <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Bestätigung" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
      <%= f.fields_for :car, @car do |car| %>
      <%= car.label :plateprefix, "Nummernschild" %>
    <div class="form-inline">
       <%= car.text_field :plateprefix %> 
       <%= car.label :plate,  "-" %>
       <%= car.text_field :plate %>
     </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>      
</div>
```

user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car, inverse_of: :users
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
```

car.rb:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :users, inverse_of: :car
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
   validates :plateprefix,  presence: true
```

and finally my car controller:

```
 def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
   if verify_recaptcha
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if Car.exists?(:country => 'D', :plateprefix => params[:user][:car][:plateprefix].upcase, :plate => params[:user][:car][:plate].upcase)
     @car = Car.find_by(:country => 'D', :plateprefix => params[:user][:car][:plateprefix].upcase, :plate => params[:user][:car][:plate].upcase)
     @user.car_id = @car.id
    else
     @car = Car.new(:country => 'D', :plateprefix => params[:user][:car][:plateprefix].upcase, :plate => params[:user][:car][:plate].upcase)
     @car.country = 'D'
     @car.save
     @user.car_id = @car.id
    end
    if @user.save
      @user.send_activation_email
      flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      @user = User.new
      render 'new'
    end
   else
    @user = User.new
     render 'new'
   end
  end
```

Comment: In addition to my question: When the error occurs and the number plates field gets marked red, it also destroys my formatting. Normally the two fields are in a line with a dash in the middle (german numberplates standard formatting) but with the red marking, it moves the fields into two seperate lines. Any hint on this one would also help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after 2 further days of reading I solved it:

First I moved the accepts_nested_attributes from the car.rb to the user.rb (and from plural to singular)

user.rb

```
 accepts_nested_attributes for :car
```

but then for some reason in my form I had to change the variable in the fields_for to plural (:cars - some of rails magic is beyond me but I am getting there I think)

Next i also recreated my controller to use the methods provided by ActiveModel/Record and went to do:

```
if Car.exists?(:country => 'D', :plateprefix => params[:user][:cars][:plateprefix].upcase, :plate => params[:user][:cars][:plate].upcase)
 @user.car = Car.find_by(:country => 'D', :plateprefix => params[:user][:cars][:plateprefix].upcase, :plate => params[:user][:cars][:plate].upcase)
else
 @user.create_car(:country => 'D', :plateprefix => params[:user][:cars][:plateprefix].upcase, :plate => params[:user][:cars][:plate].upcase)
end
```

So this cleaned up my code a bit and I finally got my errors to show properly!